# Missing focus ring/border SWT Windows 7

Tags: java, focus, swt, accessibility

I'm working with a piece of UI software implementing SWT and Java. The issue I'm seeing is that on a couple windows, controls don't show their focus ring (small dotted black line in windows).  I have been largely unsuccessful trying to find someone else with the same issue online unfortunately.

Is there a way to enable/disable the focus ring around a SWT control? The code I'm working with is fairly messy so there could very well be a good amount wrong with it, but making the focus ring/border visible is the issue I haven't been able to find anything on yet.

Comment: Some controls (`Tree` and `Table` for example) suppress the focus ring if SWT.BORDER is **not** specified (this is on Mac OS X, it might vary by platform).

Comment: I did find this issue while searching but my problem is with more basic UI elements like the check box and editable text fields.